# Document Management for Mattermost

Tags: document-management, cmis

My company uses [Mattermost](http://www.mattermost.org) (a Slack alternative) for most daily communications.

Is there a way we can [manage documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) within Mattermost?

Example use:

1. Alice creates a contract in LibreOffice and uploads it to Mattermost,
2. Bob updates it with more information (download, modify, upload to replace),
3. Charles creates another contract,
4. Danielle easily sees the list of all contracts in their most up-to-date version.

Requirements:

- Each document can be modified in the future by anyone who has permission
- All revisions of each document are clearly listed (and downloadable) in the document's history
- Documents can be organized somehow, for instance with tags or categories or folders.
- Easy way to list all documents based on the organization above (for instance by tag or category or folder)
- Full-text search: If a PDF/DOC/ODT contains a keyword I will find it by typing that keyword in Mattermost's search box
- The cheaper the better, ideally open source

It can be either a Mattermost-specific development or an [integration](https://www.mattermost.org/community-applications/) with a pure Document Management product like [Alfresco](http://alfresco.com)/[Nuxeo](http://www.nuxeo.com)/[NemakiWare](http://nemakiware.com). Special bonus if compatible with any [Enterprise Content Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management) server via the [CMIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) protocol.

The existing upload/download feature of Mattermost is not enough because:

- Documents can't be modified (re-uploadeds are treated as separate documents),
- There is no list of documents, one would have to scroll for hours to find a five year old contract without being sure it is the last version.

Comment: Four years later, I have no recommendation, but I'm curious whether you eventually found a solution.

Comment: @MikeFahy: Not yet unfortunately, anyone feel free to post solutions :-)